# Moving WordPress from Live to Localhost MAMP

Tags: wordpress, ssl, localhost, mamp

I am trying to back up my Wordpress website and want to test my website locally, without a SSL certificate. I have installed MAMP but I am facing some problems to make it work.

When I start the apache server and go the localhost, my homepage does show up but the CSS doesn't load and I get a bunch of errors regarding a cache plugin.
But the biggest problem I am facing is that whenever I go to another page, my local website immediately tries to load a HTTPS page and goes to my live website (even when I specifically mention a HTTP link).

I have tried changing the .htacces file with the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have also changed the database homepage URL from https to http in wp_options but that only fixed the index page but not the other pages of my website.

My apologies if my question is still unclear, I'm kind of new to this so any help would be appreciated.